# How to send dynamic email to multiple users(email addresses) from database table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is anyone can suggest what is the best way or how can I send email to all the users that are located in my news_subscibers table with dynamic data from a form? I tried and was a able to send email to a hard coded email.

```
 public function sendNewsEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
      'subject' => 'bail|string|required|string|max:100',
      'bodymessage' => 'bail|string|required|string|min:10',
    ]);

    $data = array(
      'subject' => $request->subject,
      'bodymessage' => $request->bodymessage
    );


    $subscriber_emails = NewsSubscriber::pluck('subs_email')->toArray();

    foreach ($subscriber_emails as $mail)
    {
    Mail::send('email.news-email', $data, $mail,  function($message) use ($data, $mail){
          $message->from('not_reply@sik.org');
          $message->to('abc@gmail.com');
          $message->cc($mail);
          $message->subject($data['subject']);
      });

      Session::flash('success', 'Your message was sent!');
      return redirect()->back();

    };


}
```

I would like to send the email to all users in news_subscribers table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just pass your array in `$message->to($subscriber_emails)` no need foreach loop to send email to multiple user

```
Mail::send('email.news-email', $data, $mail,  function($message) use ($data, $subscriber_emails){
      $message->from('not_reply@sik.org');
      $message->to($subscriber_emails);
      $message->subject($data['subject']);
  });
```

Comment: I'm getting thie error:     `call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'livreson@gmail.com' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. It will put all of the emails in the "to" list, and EVERY recipient will see all of the emails. You do not want to send all of the email addresses in your system to every person.

Comment: @Aken Roberts, I can use bcc to hide recipients emails. But Knuks suggestion worked fine. If you have better method to handle this kinda request, please share the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mailable to send multiple emails

generating new mailable

```
php artisan make:mail SampleMail
```

this command will generate a file in `app/mail/SampleMail.php`
optional write some logic in a mailable class

call mailable in controller using

```
$user = User::get(); // fetch user's to send mails
Mail::to($user)->send(new SampleMail());
```

mailable docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#generating-mailables

Answer (score 0):

You have your success flash message and returned response inside of your `$subscriber_emails` loop. This causes only the first email to send, then the loop stops and returns the redirect response.

Place those lines after to keep the loop going for all emails.

```php
public function sendNewsEmail(Request $request)
{
    // ...


    $subscriber_emails = NewsSubscriber::pluck('subs_email')->toArray();

    foreach ($subscriber_emails as $mail)
    {
        Mail::send('email.news-email', $data, $mail, function ($message) use ($data, $mail) {
            $message->from('not_reply@sik.org');
            $message->to('abc@gmail.com');
            $message->cc($mail);
            $message->subject($data['subject']);
        });
    }

    Session::flash('success', 'Your message was sent!');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

(Assuming this is your issue. If not, you should add any error messages or unexpected behavior you're experiencing.)

Comment: I'm getting thie error:

    `call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'livreson@gmail.com' not found or invalid function name`